# Is watir blocked from logging into Facebook ? If so is there another gem that can do this?

Tags: ruby, facebook, authentication, facebook-login, watir

This is my code however when running it facebook stops me logging in. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'watir'
require 'webdrivers'
require 'mechanize'

agent = Mechanize.new
agent.get('http://facebook.com') do |page|
  login_page = agent.click(page.link_with(:text => /Log In/ ))
end

proxy = {
  http: '185.10.166.130:8080',
  ssl:  '185.10.166.130:8080'
}

browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, proxy: proxy
browser.goto 'facebook.com'

# Enter Facebook login details and click login
browser.text_field(id: 'email').set '****'
browser.text_field(id: 'pass').set '****'
browser.button(type: 'submit').click
```

Comment: you say 'facebook stops me logging in', what is the actual error? or is it showing you a captcha?

Comment: I don’t think this is Watir specific. Facebook probably detects automation attempts somehow and the same would likely happen to other gems / libraries, too. Try to figure out how they do it and you may find a way to circumvent their detection.

Comment: Facebook doesn't let you automate things on facebook.com. Use the API. If the API doesn't has it then you can't do it